# How to stop content hiding behind ionic tabs?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I forked a code pen example for hiding the ionic tabs menu.

When the home page first loads, if you scroll to the very bottom the last image fits nicely above the tabs menu.

Then if you click on the "scientific facts" button at the top of the content area which goes to a page that hides the tabs menu, then go back to the home page and scroll down again, part of the last image is stuck (not visible) behind the tabs menu. How can I fix this?

Here is the link: http://codepen.io/laurencemeah/pen/RaEGKy

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('tabs', {
      url: "/tab",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
    })
    .state('tabs.home', {
      url: "/home",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
          controller: 'HomeTabCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.facts', {
      url: "/facts",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/facts.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.facts2', {
      url: "/facts2",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/facts2.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.about', {
      url: "/about",
      views: {
        'about-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/about.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.navstack', {
      url: "/navstack",
      views: {
        'about-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/nav-stack.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.contact', {
      url: "/contact",
      views: {
        'contact-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/contact.html"
        }
      }
    });


  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/tab/home");

})

.controller('HomeTabCtrl', function($scope) {
  console.log('HomeTabCtrl');
})

.directive('hideTabs', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, $el) {
      $rootScope.hideTabs = 'tabs-item-hide';
      $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        $rootScope.hideTabs = '';
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

  <title>Tabs Example</title>

  <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
    <ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-bar>

  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>


  <script id="templates/tabs.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-positive {{$root.hideTabs}}">

      <ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home" href="#/tab/home">
        <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

      <ion-tab title="About" icon="ion-ios-information" href="#/tab/about">
        <ion-nav-view name="about-tab"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

      <ion-tab title="Contact" icon="ion-ios-world" ui-sref="tabs.contact">
        <ion-nav-view name="contact-tab"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

    </ion-tabs>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Home">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <p>
          <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/facts">Scientific Facts</a>
        </p>
        <img ng-src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/54101/magic-cube-cube-puzzle-play-54101.jpeg">
        <img ng-src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/54101/magic-cube-cube-puzzle-play-54101.jpeg">
        <img ng-src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/54101/magic-cube-cube-puzzle-play-54101.jpeg">
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/facts.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view cache-view="false" id="store-visit-wrapper" hide-tabs>
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <p>This page should not show the tab-bar at the bottom</p>
        <p>Banging your head against a wall uses 150 calories an hour.</p>
        <p>Dogs have four toes on their hind feet, and five on their front feet.</p>
        <p>The ant can lift 50 times its own weight, can pull 30 times its own weight and always falls over on its right side when intoxicated.</p>
        <p>A cockroach will live nine days without it's head, before it starves to death.</p>
        <p>Polar bears are left handed.</p>
        <p>
          <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
          <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/facts2">More Facts</a>
        </p>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/facts2.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Also Factual">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <p>111,111,111 x 111,111,111 = 12,345,678,987,654,321</p>
        <p>1 in every 4 Americans has appeared on T.V.</p>
        <p>11% of the world is left-handed.</p>
        <p>1 in 8 Americans has worked at a McDonalds restaurant.</p>
        <p>$283,200 is the absolute highest amount of money you can win on Jeopardy.</p>
        <p>101 Dalmatians, Peter Pan, Lady and the Tramp, and Mulan are the only Disney cartoons where both parents are present and don't die throughout the movie.</p>
        <p>
          <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
          <a class="button icon ion-chevron-left" href="#/tab/facts"> Scientific Facts</a>
        </p>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/about.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="About">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <h3>Create hybrid mobile apps with the web technologies you love.</h3>
        <p>Free and open source, Ionic offers a library of mobile-optimized HTML, CSS and JS components for building highly interactive apps.</p>
        <p>Built with Sass and optimized for AngularJS.</p>
        <p>
          <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/navstack">Tabs Nav Stack</a>
        </p>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/nav-stack.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Tab Nav Stack">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <p>
          <img src="http://ionicframework.com/img/diagrams/tabs-nav-stack.png" style="width:100%">
        </p>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/contact.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view title="Contact">
      <ion-content>
        <div class="list">
          <div class="item">
            @IonicFramework
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            @DriftyTeam
          </div>
        </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you remove the tabs from rootScope, but never adding them back in again once you navigate away from that page. Try something else. I really don't suggest touching $rootScope, at all

https://github.com/mhartington/ion-hide-tabs